# Newbie .net question - limited access to DB...how to write models?

Tags: .net, data-access-layer

I'm new to the .net framework.

I'm about to start a project where I only have read access to the client's database.  The database doesn't have all the stored procedures that I need to query for the information my project needs.  So I need to write additional queries somewhere in my application.

Being new to .net and all, can someone recommend some "quick start" guides on what libraries/packages I need to be aware of before i start creating my own data access layer?

**Additional info**

Another .net developer told me I won't be able to use the Entity framework effectively because the person who made the database didn't explicitly declare foreign keys and db integrity constraints. If you guycan confirm this limitation, then it means I'll have to write my own queries with the ado.net library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the level you will work on.

If you need write your own sql queries, get familiar with at least the core components of [ado.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (Connection, Command, Reader).

If you will be using OR-Mapper (object-relational mapper), look into the [entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) or [linq-to-sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx).

Besides that, get familiar with [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx). It will help you with a lot of things that were hard and bloaty in earlier times.

Answer (score 1):

[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) is a great place to start, particularly when the database is already there.  Best part is it's part of the .Net stack so you don't need other packages.